# Why do all questions with a tag get marked?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, questions, tags, highlighting

I follow the questions that are tagged ["delphi"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/delphi) on stackoverflow.
Since a few weeks, when te page loads, *all* questions get the skin-tone-kind-of-pink background, nomatter from which computer I watch or which page of the questions I'm on.

Did something break? Did I break something? Is there a reset button somewhere?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you may have setup the `delphi` tag as ignored or perhaps to interesting, but interesting tags show up "highlighted" in yellow on my machine. If you go to your profile -> preferences, you can remove it from the ignored list.

EDIT:

Actually, it looks like (I'm assuming you're talking about SO here), it looks like ignored tags end up with a faded look. So I would guess that you've marked the tag as interesting and that's causing the change. I know it wasn't until a few months ago that interesting tags were highlighted when you were browsing that tags specific page, so you would have noticed this change recently.

Comment: yes all pages now respect interesting / ignored

Comment: You're right, I have Delphi as an interesting tag, but if I remember correctly, when I started using / found out about SO, only questions I had visited before got highlighted on the list with questions tagged delphi... This indication is lost to me now, since the entire list is highlighted.

Answer (score 0):

They made a change a few weeks ago where questions that carry tags on your interesting list get highlighed even when you're on the page for that tag.